# How to reduce image file size in java

Tags: java

I want to reduce image file size of an uploaded image before saving it into server (to reduce loading time). how can I do it using java?

Comment: You could save the image in a compressed format such as JPEG or PNG.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of question has been answered quite a few times on this site. I suggest you check out [How to resize the original image into a common size of image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305670/how-to-resize-the-original-image-into-a-common-size-of-image-in-java) or search for java image resize on this site.

Comment: actually i was talking about the file size(3mb -> 200 kb), not the dimentions of the image. Does it cover them also?

Comment: Yes, it's the same kind of thing -- the file size is mostly defined by the image dimensions (and potentially the image compression, depending on the format used)

Answer (score 3):

May this following code help you it will resize and keep quality of image.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
             if (!isMultipart) {
             } else {
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List items = null;
                try {
                     items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                     System.out.println("Unable to load image" +  e.getMessage());}
                Iterator itr = items.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                     System.out.println(items.size());
                       FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                       if (!item.isFormField()) {
                          try {
                                 int size = 200;// size of the new image.
                                 //take the file as inputstream.
                                 InputStream imageStream = item.getInputStream();
                                 //read the image as a BufferedImage.
                                 BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(imageStream); 
                                 //cal the sacleImage method.
                                 BufferedImage newImage = scaleImage(image, size);
                                 String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/image");
                                 //write file.
                                 File file = new File(path, "testimage.jpg");
                                 ImageIO.write(newImage, "JPG", file);
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                               System.out.println("Unable to save the image" + e.getMessage());
                               //System.out.println(path);
                  }//if
                }//iter
        }
    private BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int size) {
         double boundSize = size;
            int origWidth = bufferedImage.getWidth();
            int origHeight = bufferedImage.getHeight();
            double scale;
            if (origHeight > origWidth)
                scale = boundSize / origHeight;
            else
                scale = boundSize / origWidth;
             //* Don't scale up small images.
            if (scale > 1.0)
                return (bufferedImage);
            int scaledWidth = (int) (scale * origWidth);
            int scaledHeight = (int) (scale * origHeight);
            Image scaledImage = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            // new ImageIcon(image); // load image
            // scaledWidth = scaledImage.getWidth(null);
            // scaledHeight = scaledImage.getHeight(null);
            BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
                 g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();
            return (scaledBI);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * This will get an image file and returns a byte array resized by the given value.
 */
package tajneed;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class ImageResizer {

    public static byte[] resize(File icon) {
        try {
           BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(icon);

           originalImage= Scalr.resize(originalImage, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, 128, 153);
            //To save with original ratio uncomment next line and comment the above.
            //originalImage= Scalr.resize(originalImage, 153, 128);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            return imageInByte;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use img4java to reduce the file size of your image.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, IM4JavaException {
     IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
     //op.resize(500, 500, '>');
     //op.quality(85.0); // jpeg quality (%)
     op.strip(); 
     op.interlace("Plane");
     op.define("jpeg:extent=5kb");
     op.addImage("/home/j/Scrivania/originale.jpg"); // original file
     op.addImage("/home/j/Scrivania/nuova_m.jpg"); // destination
     
     ConvertCmd convert = new ConvertCmd();
     convert.run(op);
}
```