# How to reduce the size of image in java

Tags: java, image, size, reduce

Please help some one for how to reduce the size of image in java

my problem is

i am taking one image as input for java program and taking output as .bmp image

for creating new image i am using the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)     
         {    
              for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)   
              {  
                Color c = new Color(color2[i][j], color2[i][j], color2[i][j]);  
                image1.setRGB(i, j, c.getRGB());   
              }     
          }   
ImageIO.write(image1, "bmp", new File("hh5_binary_Adjust.bmp"));
```

but if i use the above code i am getting 6.5 mb size  for one A4 size paper
so please help me to get  a minimum length of image without modifying the file extension that is bmp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing a bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583757/resizing-a-bitmap)

Comment: You cannot magically compress a format that does not support compression.  Use PNG.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the one that you provided is about scaling the image and this one is about lowering the size(memory) of the image.

Comment: @CodingChief It might be... it could be about either... the question is a little unclear. OP wants to reduce file size, but it's not obvious whether reducing resolution or changing format is acceptable. (Obviously one of these had better be acceptable...)

Comment: If you scale it by 50% in both directions it will be around 4 times smaller in size (memory) ...

Comment: From the file name, it seems your image is binary... If you create `image1` using `new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY)`, the file size will probably become a lot smaller than 6.5 MB. But as others have pointed out, if file size matters, BMP is not the format (try JBIG if image is binary).

Comment: Following link help you refer this.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31745145/5129765

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the resolution, there isn't a good way to do this and get a really crisp output image without using an external library. I recommend [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/). I've had fantastic results with it.

But please be aware that the main reason you have a large file size is that you're using BMP as the output format! If you change that, you'll massively reduce the file size easily and cheaply. I'd go with JPG for photos, or PNG for graphics.

The `ImageIO` class will save to either of those with no trouble.