# How to resize JPG to certain filesize dealing with image dimensions(not compression)?

Tags: java, clojure, imagemagick

How to resize jpg image to fit certain bytesize?

I am implementing a client app which should send images not exeding 200KB. However some images sometimes exceed 200KB(JPG).

I tried ImageMagick, "extent" command, however it seems that it deals with compression rather than image dimensions, whereas I need to preserve  <del>compression rate</del>(Edit 1: quality) and resize only dimensions.

I am using java's ImageIO through Clojure and there also seems to be no exact solution.

Comment: check out this question if it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305670/how-to-resize-the-original-image-into-a-common-size-of-image-in-java

Comment: "I need to preserve compression rate" -- if you resize the image, it will be re-compressed.

Comment: @bakero98 I can't find the solution in the link provided.

Comment: If you resize a jpg that has a specific quality with ImageMagick and specify no different -quality value, the output should use the same quality value to recompress. Use imagemagick identify to check the quality value before and after resizing.

Comment: Another Java only thread that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951290/re-sizing-an-image-without-losing-quality